# in sql server how to create a column with date datatype and its format as YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql-server-2008, iso

In sql server how to create a column with date datatype and its format as `YYYYMMDD`.

I don't want to use query level display settings.

I have found so many options with `112`,`convert`,`cast` but all are working at query level where as I want this format at `table level` itself.

Comment: [`date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb630352.aspx) type has no implicit format like `YYYYMMDD`.  you can only `CONVERT` it to a character type using styles like 112.

Comment: Thanks ughai for ur quick responce. but my client is expecting to store the data in YYYYMMDD format only. i suggested them to change the datatype but they dont want to do that as well. if it is of 'date' datatype they can perform date functions on that column.so there is no other way.?

Comment: the display format should be controlled by the application and not how you store your data. if you start storing dates as character like `YYYYMMDD`, you have an inefficient design, validation issues, business logic issues and what not.

Comment: ughai if you dont mind can you please elaborate how it will impact the business if we store dates as YYYYMMDD

Comment: This would be helpful https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type